# DalvikVM Exception while creating Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I need to create a Fragment for a Tab and my program breaks down. I guess it's a simple mistake I made. Must have something to do with my `fragTab1`

This is what I get:

```
Pick [Android Application]  
<terminated>Pick [Android Application]  
<disconnected>DalvikVM [localhost:8600] 
Pick [Android Application]  
DalvikVM [localhost:8600] (may be out of synch) 
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2295    
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2349 
        ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 159    
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1316  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 137 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5419    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 525  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1187 
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 1003    
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running) (may be out of synch)  
    Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) (may be out of synch)
```

Following is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_launch);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    ActionBar.Tab fragTab1 = actionbar.newTab().setText(R.string.tabBar_1);
    Fragment fragmentQuiz = new Fragment();
    fragmentQuiz.getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.fragment_app_launch, null);
    fragTab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentQuiz));
    actionbar.addTab(fragTab1);

    ActionBar.Tab fragTab2 = actionbar.newTab().setText(R.string.tabBar_2);
    Fragment fragmentStatistics = new FragmentStatistics();
    fragTab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentStatistics));
    actionbar.addTab(fragTab2);

    /*ActionBar.Tab fragTab3 = actionbar.newTab().setText(R.string.tabBar_3);
    Fragment fragmentProVersion = new FragmentProVersion();
    fragTab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentProVersion));
    actionbar.addTab(fragTab3);*/

 }
```

Comment: Can you please upload the error log in question ?

Comment: I did, sorry, I was too late :-)

Comment: Please post a more complete stack trace. It's possible that your activity doesn't have access to the ActionBar, but I can't tell from the single error line.

Comment: you should upload full error log. Sometimes single error line doesnt helps much.

Comment: done! it highlighted this line, that´s why I pnly copied this line